# Email Templates: Gmail ignores HTML u tag

Tags: html, css, html-email, email-templates

RESOLVED: issue caused by HTML sanitizer

I'm creating an email template in JSON and I have an underlined word, e.g:

```
<ul><li><u style=\"text-decoration: underline;\"> Date:</u> Post must be shared on Instagram within one week of receiving your product</li></ul>
```

When I send myself my template and receive it in Gmail, the underlines are gone. There is no text decoration whatsoever. But my bolded text (using the  tag) works great.

****NOTE: I tried adding inline-styling as suggested, but this does not work. I should also mention this text is in a list, so it has a parent li tag. Not sure why this would make a difference.

Has anyone run into this? I didn't see much on it while googling, which makes me wonder if there is a workaround.

Comment: Email clients, like Gmail, may be normalizing the inherit styles of tags like `u`. Have you tried using an *inline style* instead? e.g: `text-decoration: underline;`

Comment: Thanks for the tip but this didn't work.

Comment: @KiraPilot can you also add the `ul` and `li` tag which contains this element?

Comment: no problemo @signo added!

Comment: Any particular reason you need to escape the double-quotation marks? :/

Comment: Yeah, I'm using a JSON block here. Sorry...updated question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out what was happening, and it's non-gmail related. We're using an HTML sanitizer on the back end, and the  tag was not included. Once I explicitly added it, my email sent without issue. Thank you to everyone who took a look.

Comment: Just a tip that saved me hours, you can right click->inspect element on Gmail in order to see what the body of the received e-mail looks like (to check if tags/styles are missing)

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You could add custom styling:
`<u style="text-decoration: underline;"></u>`